# why variable address not change - c programming

Tags: c

I declare a variable `x` in each iteration of the for loop. Why the address of `x` remains the same?

```
int main(void) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    int x = i;
    printf("x = %d", x);
    printf(" &x = %d", &x);
    printf("\n");
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

```
output

x = 0 &x = 1508435624                                                                      
x = 1 &x = 1508435624                                                                      
x = 2 &x = 1508435624                                                                      
x = 3 &x = 1508435624                                                                      
x = 4 &x = 1508435624
```

If I want to have an array of pointer to int, `int ** arr`, do I need to initialize the variables separately because the address does not change in for loop, such as

```
int num0 = 0;
int num1 = 1;
int num2 = 2;

int * arr[] = {&num0, &num1, &num2};
```

Is there an easier way for the task?

Thank you!

Comment: The easier way is just to declare an array of `int`. Then your array of pointers can point to the elements of the array of `int`s. But it's not clear why you need an array of pointers. You might want to [edit] the question to explain that.

Comment: `x` is declared on the stack, and thus it will likely be reusing the same memory each iteration... why do you expect it to move?

Comment: You cut vegetables for the Sunday dinner each week. Surprisingly you always do it on the same cuting board in your kitchen, which you put on almost exactly the same place each time. What I am trying to illustrate is that there is no reason for the compiler (linker whatever) to create that temporary local variable in a different part of the memory, because the situation 8including the number and size of other local temporary variables) is always identical.

Answer (score 5):

There's no requirement for a local variable to have a different (or the same) address each time it is instantiated.

Regardless of that, if you intend on saving the address of that variable when the loop ends you'll run into [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because your pointer will point to memory that is no longer in use.

You would need to dynamically allocate memory for each array member for them to be distinct and to prevent having to create separate variables.

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure without looking at the generated assembly code, but I would guess that in each iteration the `int x` variable is using an address on the top of the stack, and then being discarded at the end of the iteration so that the next iteration uses the same memory address.

To get an array of pointers to ints you can just declare it:

```
int *arr[NUM_INTS];
```

You can then refer to an individual int pointer with `arr[0]` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your compiler decided to optimize your code or maybe it's because it gets allocated on top of the stack every time and the stack doesn't really move so it gets the same stack address every time but we can't be sure without seeing your assembly, you can check [Stack-based memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation) if you want to know more about it.